# How can I produce an image (i.e. PNG) on the server side by using Flot.JS Library + my data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, flot

Currently I have some code that uses Flot.js library + some data to produce a graph on the client side using HTML canvas.  The resulting canvas is then encoded into BASE64 format and sent over HTTP from the client to the server.  On the server side the request is decoded, BASE64 is extracted and saved as a PNG image.  The image is used later for a PDF report.

Below is a working example of Flot.JS for how it produces the Canvas.  In my code I later convert the canvas into an BASE64 encoding of the image using code like this:

```
var canvas = plot.getCanvas();
return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

**Problem**

The above works for me just fine, but it has a side-effect of that it works on the *client-side* and client can see the temporary step, which is the graph generation and the canvas and the wait period while canvas encoding is sent over HTTP.  I really only need the "image of graph be generated and saved on the server side".

**Question**

How can I make the entire process run on the server side?

Process is:

- generate flot chart on canvas
- save canvas as an PNG image on the server side

I am totally new to running any JS on the server side, so I am seeking an answer to see if what I want is possible, and how, and if it can be done with a library such as Flot.JS and its plugins.

```js
$(function() {

   var oilPrices = [
     [1167692400000, 61.05],
     [1167778800000, 58.32],
     [1167865200000, 57.35],
     [1220824800000, 106.34]
   ];

   var exchangeRates = [
     [1167606000000, 0.7580],
     [1167692400000, 0.7580],
     [1220824800000, 0.7010],
     [1220911200000, 0.70050]
   ];

   var data = [{
     data: oilPrices,
     label: "Oil price ($)"
   }, {
     data: exchangeRates,
     label: "USD/EUR exchange rate",
     yaxis: 2
   }];

   var options = {
     canvas: true,
     xaxes: [{
       mode: "time"
     }],
     yaxes: [{
       min: 0
     }, {
       position: "right",
       alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
       tickFormatter: function(value, axis) {
         return value.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) + "€";
       }
     }],
     legend: {
       position: "sw"
     }
   }

   $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);

   $("input").change(function() {
     options.canvas = $(this).is(":checked");
     $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
   });

   // Add the Flot version string to the footer

   $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
 });
```

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.canvas.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <h2>Canvas text</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">

  <div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:600px;height:200px"></div>
  </div>

  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Enable canvas text</input>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need a library to generate graphs in server side, so you only need request the temporary image or generated image.

Comment: That will help, yes.  However my department did use such a server side library, but it was no longer being developed, and was deprecated.  We switched to a JS library because of the active development in JS libraries such as Flot or Google Charts.  The customization, plus the look and feel that JS Libraries offered looked much better than PHP server-side libraries, which we could find.  This created a problem I am trying to resolve.

Comment: Same problem here :)

Comment: You could look into a headless browser or something like http://phantomjs.org/.